# SQL parameterized query not showing result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have following function in my DataAcess class, but it is not showing any result.
My code is as follow:

```
public List<Products> GetProduct(string productName)
 {
    System.Data.DataSet ds = null;
    db = DBWrapper.GetSqlClientWrapper();
    db.ClearParameters();
    db.AddParameter(db.MakeInParam("@ProductName", DbType.String, 30, productName));
    string query = @"SELECT ProductId   
                     FROM [Products]   
                     WHERE Name LIKE '%@ProductName%'";
    ds = db.GetDataSet(query);
    db.ClearParameters();
        // Rest of Code
 }
```

I also tried:

```
string query = @"SELECT ProductId    
                 FROM [Products]   
                 WHERE Name LIKE '%"+"@ProductName"+"%'";
```

But it runs fine without parameterized like:

```
string query = @"SELECT ProductId  
                 FROM [Products]   
                 WHERE Name LIKE '%"+productName+"%'";
```

How to write this with parameterized using **@ProductName**???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
LIKE '%' + @ProductName + '%'
```

instead of

```
LIKE '%@ProductName%'
```

Why? Because  in query, your parameter is inside quotes. In quotes, SQL will recognize it as a [*string literal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) and **never** sees it as a parameter.

As an alternative, you can use your `% %` part in your `AddParameter` method as 
[Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652266/447156)*.

Answer (score 3):

Try, instead:

```
db.AddParameter(db.MakeInParam("@ProductName", DbType.String, 30, "%" + productName + "%"));
string query = @"SELECT ProductId   
                 FROM [Products]   
                 WHERE Name LIKE @ProductName";
```

SQL doesn't look for parameters *inside* of literal strings. So you can make the parameter  be the *entire* string argument for the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Thanx Damien, It also works but I like Soner's way easy (somehow) :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a parameter, you can also use:

```
string query = String.Format("Select ProductId FROM Products where Name LIKE '{0}'", productName);
```

Comment: @Sohail - okay Soner came to your rescue :)